# Java AudioSystem can't read AIFF from a CD

Tags: java, audio, javasound

A part of my program has to read AIFF files using Java  AudioSystem. The standard AudioSystem implementation does not support AIFF-C (compressed AIFF for audio CDs). I am looking either for an extension to AudioSystem which supports AIFF-C or easy way to convert AIFF-C to AIFF